# getting outofboundsexception after random generation of object list

Tags: java, math, random, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a list of objects each having some 'qid'. `qid` is in integer. 'qid' of the list start from any no say 'min' and ends at any no say 'max'. Please note that the 'qid' of the objects in the list is not continuous. Means say for example : min = 6 and max = 31 but there are only 16 object in this with their qid in `[min,max]` (min and max both including) hence there are no any object exists with no of (31-6+1)-16 = 10 qids. Means with these ten qids, no any object exists. However only 16 objects exists with thier valid qid.

Now I have an int array exactly of size 10 in which I want to store randomly ten objects in it but with their valid qid. Means these ten objects must be from those 16 NOT from those 26.

And I am doing the following

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    checkList[j] = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
    if (qidList.get(checkList[j]) == null ) {
        j--;
        continue;
    } else {
        finalList.add(j,qidList.get(checkList[j])); 
    }
}
```

1. qidList = original list with 16 valid objects with valid qid out of 26 objects with max = 31 and min = 6.
2. finalList = the final list where the randomly selected 10 objects (out of 16 NOT out of 26) will be stored.
3. checkList = integer array of size 10 where only the qid's (not other attributes) of randomly selected 10 finalList objects is to be stored.

I am getting `indexoutofboundsexception`. Can someone help me?

Comment: which line exactly is giving the outofbounds?

Comment: what is the type of qidList? is it an ArrayList?

Comment: No its an ObjectList. And sorry. the exception on which line is not clear to me. As i am not getting any server error log. Only the browser is showing that outofboundsException. what should i do now..?

Comment: I think part of our problem in helping you is that your explanation of what precisely is contained in the various lists isn't completely clear, particularly the last two or three sentences of the first paragraph. It seems clear that the issue is that some checkList[j] is not contained in qidList, but apart from that, it's hard to say WHY without more context.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are decrementing j inside the for loop, you are probably going past 0 (i.e. -1 and beyond) and this is throwing an indexOutOfBounds

EDIT:

Based on the comment that the error occurs at the line "qidList.get(checkList[j]) == null" then clearly qidList does not have checkList[j] which means the line above "checkList[j] = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));" is being set to a value outside of the size of qidList!

Print out the value of checkList[j] to debug!

Comment: I don't think this can be it, because there's a 'continue;' immediately after j--; This means that j-- will happen at most once per loop, and since it's also incremented once per loop... I could be wrong though

Comment: hi barbiepylon : i accept j is decrementing inside loop that is only when invalid qid if taken. Then i am setting continue and j is again incremented with j++ as shown in for loop and get back to its previous position. if 0 then on 0, if 3 then on 3. so what harm in it. when i am sure that 16 out of 26 is valid.?

Comment: O, I was mistaken as to what exactly a continue did.

Comment: Read my edit. You are setting checkList[j] to something  < 0 or > size of list. Add a print statement below checkList[j] to see what the value is!

Comment: Yes checklist having some invalid qid's. Where is the problem now..?

Comment: Well without knowing what min and max equal its hard to say the exact problem. For example, with max = 31, min = 6. Your checkList[j] could potentially = 32. 6 + (int) (1 * (31 - 6) + 1) = 32. If qidList only has 16 objects then obviously qidList.get(32) is out of bounds!

Comment: max is already set to qidList.size()-1. that is 31. and min=6. I confirm these by printing from program. but i must say your previous example may be correct. But i dont have any more code important. Can u help me out within these code. i gave all the for loop where problem is existing.

Comment: Well, what exactly are you trying to do in the line that it fails? Why are you computing "max-min+1"....?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment (now apparently deleted), it appears like the problem is with `qidList.get`, as if the problem was with `checkList[j]`, it would have thrown an exception on the line before.  Thus, check that max is less than the size of qidList.  If not, you can get the following IndexOutOfBoundsException on the get method.  From the [List API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29):

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())
```

**Update:**
To guard against this, change it to the following:

```
if ((checkList[j] >= qidList.size()) || (qidList.get(checkList[j]) == null)) {
    j--;
    continue;
}
```

Or better yet, set `max` to `qidList.size() - 1` before you enter the loop

Comment: yes i have done these all what u said. But yet the problem still exists. Actually after printing the checkList[] i see some invalid qid's. I don't know from where it is being generated even after making changes as u said.

Comment: @Rambo:  You might consider adding some System.println() statements to output different values that might cause problems, and/or setting a debug breakpoint and walking through the method till just before it errors, and it should be clear why it is failing (an index on one of the arrays will be too big or too small).